# Web Parts auto-adjust to web part zone

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, visual-web-part, web-part-zone

We have developed some custom web parts in SharePoint 2016. We have developed these web parts as Visual Web Parts but with JavaScript/jQuery/REST API/PNP JS. We have used bootstrap for responsive designing.

We have set width of each web parts to 100%. Now client wants the web parts to auto-adjust according to the web part zone. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Page Layout is designed using bootstrap, I think that would achieve the purpose. The web parts will auto adjust to the web part zone's width.

Comment: thanks for your response. Any reference I may get. Any article will do.